# Accessing an EC2 instance launched into a VPC without public IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am launching an instance into my VPC on AWS and assigning a security group to that instance that allows access to the relevant ports (including 22 for SSH) from the CIDR block of my VPC as well as my personal IP address. When I launched the instance, I chose NOT to assign a public IP address, thinking that I would be able to access the instance using the private IP address. However, when I try SSH'ing into the machine, it simply hangs and fails to connect.

So, what do I need to do to be able to SSH into the instance within my VPC without assigning a  public IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a bastion host in the same network to jump into that machine. The bastion can be started on demand and use ssh agent forwarding to be transparent and safe. Using a VPN or Direct Connect to reach the private network would be more complex alternative, but useful if more hosts need to connect.